# https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture is not working on mobile device and test users

Tags: image, facebook, profile

Is it only me or the url for getting facebook profile picture is not working like before?
In the past the https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture was working and redirect to fb cdn.
now on mobile devices I get redirect to m.facebook.com/platform/profilepic which ends up with no picture at all,
and on desktop to https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic which ends with the profile image as expected but still not the fb cdn like before.

what was changed? I don't see anything on the documentation? 
Do you experience it too?

Furthermore, I can't get the profile images for my fb test users in all platforms...just get an empty image...I didn't change anything in code or fb app.

Any ideas?

*** for some reason I can't post an answer :)
it's a bug being reporter on FB which is now being fixed.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/261587761048160/

Comment: Yes I am getting a 404 on test user profile images URLs.

Comment: I opened a bug in FB, they are working on fixing it

Comment: Same here... April 19th and the issue is still happening.

Comment: I get 404s on production users as well. The reason quite simply is that Facebook are shithouse. Yes the profile image may be reset once the user logs on but that doesn't help the other users who (until then) see a blank image.